# Compilation error when building a custom kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, git

I'm trying to build a custom kernel from a git repository on my Ubuntu virtual machine. I run the make command as follows :

```
sudo apt-get install vim libncurses5-dev gcc make git exuberant-ctags
mkdir -p git/kernels; cd git/kernels
git clone -b staging-next git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/staging.git
cd staging
cp /boot/config-`uname -r`* .config
make olddefconfig
make menuconfig
make
```

The build process ends with the following error.

> ```
> drivers/staging/media/cxd2099/cxd2099.c: In function ‘slot_reset’:  
> drivers/staging/media/cxd2099/cxd2099.c:537:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘if’  
> make[4]:  [drivers/staging/media/cxd2099/cxd2099.o] Error 1  
> make[3]:  [drivers/staging/media/cxd2099] Error 2  
> make[2]:  [drivers/staging/media] Error 2  
> make[1]:  [drivers/staging] Error 2  
> make:  [drivers] Error 2
> ```

How should I repair this error?

Comment: It's just a compiler error.Go to that file and fix it(Expecting semicolon). Otherwise take a stable release and build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

staging-next is, as of right now, currently broken, specifically `f823182bc289` of staging-next is broken.

If you really want to use staging-next, check out `fcf1b73d08cd`, which is near the top and *does* compile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's the development version of the kernel from `gregkh` git repository. It's not a stable version, so it might have errors.

If you want a stable one, you need to use `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`